# Multiple IPv6 address based on SLAAC prefix on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I'd like to ask is there any way to make linux get more than one (or let we say 1000) IPv6 address base on SLAAC announced prefix?

I used to do `ip a add IPV6_ADDR` on boot when I have a static IPv6 prefix, but now my ISP gives a dynamic prefix instead of a fixed one, which makes the added addresses expire after they changed the prefix.

An alternative way I've thought is to make a script run when the prefix is changed to re-add IPs with new prefix, but I didn't find how to do it too :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: It cames out I can use `macvlan` to solve this problem.

```
~# ip link add link eth0 eth0.2 type macvlan
~# ip link set dev eth0.2 up
```